# Iterating through foreach loop - group sorting effiiceny

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting, loops

I have a loop running in my project that I am not happy with and wondered if there is a more efficient way of achieving this?

I have an array like so

```
$myarray = ["value1", "value2", "value3"];
```

Then I want to go through another object ($sponsors) and only print out values on that has a field that matches the value in $myarray[]. Like so:

```
<?php foreach ($myarray as $value): ?>

  <?php foreach ($sponsors as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );?>

       <?php if($post['someValue'] == $value): ?>

           //Do the work

       <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is working fine, but it might mean 50-60 loops just to grab and print out a few bits of markup. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT NOTE: (based on initial replies) The order of the $myarray is important, this allows me to group the 'value1' together and then 'value2' etc

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why all these **<?php** at each line? Was there some HTML that you have removed?

Comment: Thanks bub. Yes. It's just for readability as there are lots of html I have removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of outer foreach loop

```
<?php foreach ($sponsors as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );?>

   <?php if(in_array($post['someValue'], $myarray)): ?>
       //Do the work

   <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Given `$sponsers` is an array of `posts`, You can improve peformance by filterig posts based on some value by native `array_filter()` function So there are less posts for `foreach` to iterate over.

After this there is no need for  `if` statement which will also improve performance.

```
<?php foreach ($myarray as $value): ?>

<?php $filteredPosts = array_filter($sponsors, function($post) use ($value) { return $post['someValue'] == $value; }); ?>

  <?php foreach ($filteredPosts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );?>

      // do something

  <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the reason i did this was so I could get all the 'value1' matches from $myarray grouped together then all the 'value2' values etc. Grouping them together.

Comment: Ahh I understand. I have updated my answer that may help you improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

use  `in_array`

> ref [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) from here

```
 <?php 
   foreach ($sponsors as $post) {
      setup_postdata( $post );
      if(in_array($post['someValue'],$myarray){
             //Do the work
      }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array` function

it takes three parameter but one is optional

for e.g. :

```
 in_array($value, $myarray )
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and show an example so the readers know what you are talking about.